# Google Play Developer Console shows app as unsigned

Tags: android, android-studio

I got the error: [JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imXA8.png), when I try to publish my brand new app on the Play Store. I have tried [checking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TN2r.png) the V1, V2, and both boxes together, none of them solved the issue. That seems to be the only solution I can find.

I am using [app-release.apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQYor.png) and there are no errors upon the signed APK being built.

Comment: Hi ThomoJames97, looks like you're new in stackoverflow. You didn't tell the steps you took to build your APK (or app bundle?). Again, please send a screenshot of V1, V2 boxes because I don't remember doing that when I published my app.

Comment: Did you create a app release channel?

Comment: Make sure, the apk's filename is app-release.apk in the release directory of your project. This is the APK to be used for publishing. Also, check your build variant in the IDE. https://developer.android.com/studio/run#changing-variant

Comment: @SukantKumar Sorry, I've added the screenshots as requested. Yes, I created the release channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised as I took the screenshots that I wasn't logged into the owner account and hadn't yet accepted the terms of service to allow Google to manage app signing.

I contacted Google and asked for the owner email, which happened to be one I made years ago, then was allowed to accept and upload my app. Thanks all.

This is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you generate `release` type of your `.APK` doesn't mean it's being automatically signed. You need to get familiar with [this steps](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) to sign your app.

Bottom line, you need to generate a release key that will be used to sign your builds. This can be done various ways, the easiest one being following Android Studio IDE steps in

`Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK`

Comment: That is what I did, as one can see in the title bar of the second screenshot.